# getLayoutInflator() in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-inflate

I have read the android documentation about getLayoutInflator and I am still not understanding what it does. Can someone give me a use case for this method or may be during what time would you want to call getLayoutInflator?

Comment: You need a Layout Inflator when you want to Inflate a Layout...

Comment: isn't it done automatically when you do setContentView()?

Comment: yes, in the case of `setContentView()` this is handled for you, but that is one situation of many when dealing with Layouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML Layouts in Android need to be Inflated (parsed into View objects) before they are used.  `getLayoutInflator()` gets you an instance of the LayoutInflator that will allow you to manually inflate layouts for specific uses.

One example being in a Custom `ArrayAdapter` to populate a `ListView` with a Custom Layout.

You need to manually inflate and populate your desired Layout for each individual list item in the `ArrayAdapter`'s overridden `getView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setContentView()` when you're in an `Activity`. That method inflates the layout and displays the selected layout as the view for that Activity. But when you're NOT in an Activity and you need to work with a layout file, you have to inflate it to get access to the view objects in the XML.